# How should we treat questions about plugins and such "software-parts"?

Tags: discussion, questions

I made a ["test-drive" question about plugins](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1496/auto-indentation-in-notepad).

But, how should we treat those kind of question, that doesn't ask for a application itself, just a dll or plugin like software?

Comment: You're extended these questions ([browser plugins](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/228/are-questions-about-browser-plugins-acceptable) and [minecraft plugins](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/237/would-plugin-recommendations-about-minecraft-be-on-topic)), and I think thaht the answer is the same **yes**

Answer (score 4):

Treat them like every other software as well.

They are totally on topic and don't need any special treatment.

If you can give good recommendations on why to use which one, answer them.

If you can't see if you can improve the question, vote and flag as you see fit.