# Is asking for Wordpress plugins on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

So asking about the Wordpress's plugins has been rejected by the Wordpress Development. Do we count the plugins as softwares also? I see that asking for plugins for Minecraft is acceptable, so I don't think plugins for Wordpress should be an exception. Any idea?

- [Would plugin recommendations about Minecraft be on topic?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/237/6389)
- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: For reference, currently we have 50 questions tagged with [tag:wordpress], many of which ask for plugins.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't see why Wordpress plugins should be an exception here. For reference:

- [Would plugin recommendations about Minecraft be on topic?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/237/185) → **OK**
- [How should we treat questions about plugins and such “software-parts”?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/603/185) → **OK**
- [Are questions about browser plugins acceptable?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/185) → **OK**

Cetero censeo: **OK** – or in other words: Such requests are fully acceptable, as long as they stick to our other rules (especially our [quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) :)

Comment: Very well. I have asked this in the meta of Wordpress SE: [For who's looking for plugin recommendation, should we suggest them to ask in Software Recomendation?](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/4074/64282)

Comment: For some food: you might wish to take a look at my [collection of canned responses for Android.SE](https://gist.github.com/IzzySoft/58ba94af51720ef8adeb) (an export to be used with [SE-AutoReviewComments](https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments)), and especially see the first entry ("App recommendation"). That's an example of how you could deal with it, as long as there's no "official migration path".